# Can I specify "or" with keyword "where" an Generic Type Parameters Constraints?

Tags: c#

I have a function to do scrambled comparison

```
    public static int ScrambledEquals<TKey, T>(
      IDictionary<TKey, T> list1, 
      IDictionary<TKey, T> list2)
        where TKey : IComparable
        where T : ICompareAsHtml or IComparable // compilation failure on this line
    {
      // ...
    }

    public static int ScrambledEquals<TKey, T>(
      IDictionary<TKey, T> list1, 
      IDictionary<TKey, T> list2)
        where TKey : IComparable
        where T : ICompareAsHtml {} // This works!
```

The TKey has to be IComparable, but the value type T can be IComparable or implementing below interface

```
    public interface ICompareAsHtml
    {
      // Compare current "this" object with "obj"
      // and persist the difference in html somewhere
      // return number of differences.
      int compareAsHtml(object obj);
    }
```

How can I update where line to make compilation pass (not delete it, not use one of the interfaces)?

Or better, you can read my code below to understand my situation. I need to use below function to compare a collection of string, which is IComparable; or compare a collection of hug class, say Sales, which implementing ICompareAsHtml but not IComparable. (Because too many properties to make this class very hard to implement CompareTo function - Not able to give out "one" number to represent the "direction" and "distance" between two instances.)

```
    public static int ScrambledEquals<TKey, T>(
      IDictionary<TKey, T> list1,
      IDictionary<TKey, T> list2)
    where TKey : IComparable
    // where T : ICompareAsHtml or IComparable
    // commented out above line to make compilation pass
    {
        int nDIff = 0;
        List<TKey> bothKeys = list1.Keys.Union<TKey>(list2.Keys).ToList();
        bothKeys.Sort();
        foreach (TKey key in bothKeys)
        {
            // code omitted - not related to this question 
            {
                    // key exist in both lists.
                    object o1 = list1[key];
                    object o2 = list2[key];
                    if (o1 is IComparable && o2 is IComparable)
                    {
                        IComparable v1 = (IComparable)o1;
                        IComparable v2 = (IComparable)o2;
                        if (0 != v1.CompareTo(v2))
                        {
                            nDIff++;
                            // Save the difference in html
                        }
                    }
                    else if (o1 is ICompareAsHtml && o2 is ICompareAsHtml)
                    {
                        ICompareAsHtml v1 = (ICompareAsHtml)o1;
                        ICompareAsHtml v2 = (ICompareAsHtml)o2;
                        // Save the difference
                        nDIff += v1.compareAsHtml(v2);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // If I can use where keyword
                        // I don't need this exception
                        throw new Exception(@"Error: Program error
    - Value Type is neither IComparable nor ICompareAsHtml.");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return nDIff;
    }
```

All suggestion / feedback / comments are welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I figured out to use two functions instead of one

```
public static int ScrambledEqualsComparable<TKey, T>(
  IDictionary<TKey, T> list1, 
  IDictionary<TKey, T> list2)
    where TKey : IComparable
    where T : IComparable
{
  return ScrambledEquals(list1, list2);
}

public static int ScrambledEqualsCompareAsHtml<TKey, T>(
  IDictionary<TKey, T> list1, 
  IDictionary<TKey, T> list2)
    where TKey : IComparable
    where T : ICompareAsHtml 
{
  return ScrambledEquals(list1, list2);
}

private static int ScrambledEquals<TKey, T>(
  Dictionary<TKey, T> list1, 
  Dictionary<TKey, T> list2)
    where TKey : IComparable
{
  // the same as above code - No need to throw exception as 
  // it has to be one of ICompareAsHtml or IComparable.
}
```

Sure, I can rename ScrambledEqualsCompareAsHtml, ScrambledEqualsComparable to proper names. But two functions can solve this problem. Sure old function changed to private to avoid direct access from outside.

How do you feel this solution?

Comment: If you make the last method private, you don't have to worry about throwing. (Deleted earlier comment about getting rid of `T` in the first two--read about co[ntra]variance too recently and thought it was possible.)

Comment: Great. Love your idea here.

Answer (score 3):

This is *not* something supported by the framework. However, the need to do this implies there is a missing common interface that both `IComparable` and `ICompareAsHtml` should implement that you could constrain to, instead.

The bad news here is that `IComparable` is part of the framework, meaning you can't change it to implement that missing interface. The good news is that `IComparable` is already pretty simple... perhaps it can *be* that missing interface.

`ICompareAsHtml` isn't part of the framework, and not mentioned in the docs for any product I can currently search via Google, meaning it's likely an interface you can change. If that's true, just make `ICompareAsHtml` implement `IComparable` and just constrain to `IComparable`, and you will meet your conditions

Comment: this interface IS in my question. with one function compareAsHtml().

Comment: Ah... I missed it in the middle of the question. All you have to do, then, is make that interface also inherit/implement IComparable, and then you can just constrain to IComparable.

Comment: See my comment to Gabe Perez's answer. I want one of them, not both of them.

Comment: `ICompareAsHtml` **logically implies** `IComparable`... just make the `CompareTo()` method that you need for `IComparable` call to `compareAsHtml()` for it's result. This **will** give you what you need.

Comment: For a hug class, like Sales, it's very hard to implement CompareTo(), but could implement CompareAsHtml for its value types and call this function again for each of its collections.

Comment: If you've already implemented `ICompareAsHtml`, the **worst** case to implement `IComparable` is to call `compareAsHtml()` from the `CompareTo()` method.

Comment: CompareTo() need to return an integer to represent the "direction" and "distance" between two instances. this is very hard for huge class like Sales. compareAsHtml() just need list all the differences which is not hard with loop and recursive.

Comment: That's not true. CompareTo only needs to return negative, 0, or positive. Distance does not matter.

Comment: For huge class like Sales, I don't know the best algorithm to return positive or negative number for two instances. I know they are different, I know where different; but I cannot find one integer to represent this difference and make it reversible: `A.CompareTo(B)` via `B.CompareTo(A)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do an OR on the constraint list, check the documentation here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx

Maybe what you could you is have your interface derive from IComparable:

```
public interface ICompareAsHtml : IComparable
{
    int compareAsHtml(object obj);
}

class CompareAsHtml : ICompareAsHtml
{
    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        return compareAsHtml(obj);
    }

    public int compareAsHtml(object obj)
    {
        //do the core comparison here and return
    }
}
```

Comment: <Maybe what you could...> No. You can see from my code, if value Type implementing compareAsHtml() function, this function doesn't need any more information from type T. alternatively, if this value type T can compare, we can compare here and persist the difference in html.

Comment: I've updated my snippet with more details. In this case any ICompareAsHtml is also IComparable so you only need the IComparable constraint.

Comment: Mmm... Not exactly I wanted. Type T can be IComparable, For example, string, That's one of my situation. In other situation, ToString() is not easy to implement for huge class like Sales, then using ICompareAsHtml to implement compareAsHtml() function. So I want type T could implement one of ICompareAsHtml or IComparable, not necessary both. In simple, I want a OR relation between these two interfaces, not AND relation of them. It seems NOT CAPABLE to do so from msdn web site, as you found in the very beginning.